# BackUp and Restore Sql Database By Admin User in Asp.Net, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

Here, I have show my c# code for BackUp and Restore with Sql Database

In that back up is working properly but when i try to restore the database from backup folder, that time one error is occurred, and the error is:

> RESTORE cannot process database 'UsersDB' because it is in use
>   by this session. It is recommended that the master database be used
>   when performing this operation. RESTORE DATABASE is terminating
>   abnormally.

BackUp button:

```
protected void btnbackup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sqlcon.ConnectionString = (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ToString());
        string destdir = "C:\\backupdb";
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(destdir))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\backupdb");
        }
        try
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
            sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("backup database UsersDB to disk='" + destdir + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss") + ".Bak'", sqlcon);
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("Backup database successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error During backup database!");
        }
    }
```

Restore Button:

```
 protected void btnrestore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {


        sqlcon.ConnectionString = (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ToString());
        sqlcon.Open();
        string destdir = "C:\\backupdb\\11082014_121403.Bak";

        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("Restore database UsersDB from disk='C:11082014_143650.Bak' ", sqlcon);
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("restore database successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error During backup database!");
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message itself saying that you can't connect to the exact database that you connected to.

You need to change your connection string so that instead of,

```
initial catalog=test_db
```

use this,

```
initial_catalog=master.
```

Answer (score 1):

In the connection string you have connected to the database you want to backup.

Instead, connect to a different database or no database at all and it will work.